# Node.JS Express basic authentication on https

Tags: node.js, express, https, basic-authentication

I'm trying to setup an https server and I want to use Basic auth on a route. For that I use a router to manage post requests. If I use the code below however I receive a 200 OK answer without setting the Authorization header. If instead I use `app.listen(PORT)` I actually need to send it (desired behavior). Why does this solution ignore basic auth?

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const express = require('express');

function getUnauthorizedResponse(req) {
    return req.auth
        ? ('Credentials ' + req.auth.user + ':' + req.auth.password + ' rejected')
        : 'No credentials provided'
}

var app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Content-Length': message.length + ''});
    response.write("OK");
    response.end();
});

app.use(
    '/',
    basicAuth({
        users: {
            'username':'pwd'
        },
        challenge: true,
        unauthorizedResponse: getUnauthorizedResponse
    }),
    router
);

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.key', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('sslcert/server.cert', 'utf8')
};

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: `app.listen(PORT)` creates an http server.  Your other code creates an https server.

Comment: Is it possible to enable basic auth on the https server as well?

Comment: Yes, that module works just fine with an https server.  I'd suggest changing your `app.use()` to remove the `"/"` so there is no path argument.  Just go `app.use(basicAuth(...), router);`.  And, then make absolutely sure you're testing the right port and https protocol and that the server is NOT running before you start your code (in case a previous older version of the server is still running).